# Why 'whereis' and 'which' don't show me location of command?

Tags: bash

What are the reasons why commands like `whereis` or `which` do not show me location of command? E.g. I have nvm and want to know where is it located, but none of these command help me to find the binary. Should I use only `find` in this case?

**UPDATE**

Here is long output of `type nvm`

```
$ type nvm
nvm is a function
nvm ()
{
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        nvm help;
        return;
    fi;
    local uname="$(uname -a)";
    local os=;
    local arch="$(uname -m)";
    case "$uname" in
        Linux\ *)
            os=linux
        ;;
        Darwin\ *)
            os=darwin
        ;;
        SunOS\ *)
            os=sunos
        ;;
        FreeBSD\ *)
            os=freebsd
        ;;
    esac;
    case "$uname" in
        *x86_64*)
            arch=x64
        ;;
        *i*86*)
            arch=x86
        ;;
        *armv6l*)
            arch=arm-pi
        ;;
    esac;
    local VERSION;
    local ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS;
    case $1 in
        "help")
            echo;
            echo "Node Version Manager";
            echo;
            echo "Usage:";
            echo "    nvm help                    Show this message";
            echo "    nvm install [-s] <version>  Download and install a <version>, [-s] from source";
            echo "    nvm uninstall <version>     Uninstall a version";
            echo "    nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>";
            echo "    nvm run <version> [<args>]  Run <version> with <args> as arguments";
            echo "    nvm current                 Display currently activated version";
            echo "    nvm ls                      List installed versions";
            echo "    nvm ls <version>            List versions matching a given description";
            echo "    nvm ls-remote               List remote versions available for install";
            echo "    nvm deactivate              Undo effects of NVM on current shell";
            echo "    nvm alias [<pattern>]       Show all aliases beginning with <pattern>";
            echo "    nvm alias <name> <version>  Set an alias named <name> pointing to <version>";
            echo "    nvm unalias <name>          Deletes the alias named <name>";
            echo "    nvm copy-packages <version> Install global NPM packages contained in <version> to current version";
            echo;
            echo "Example:";
            echo "    nvm install v0.10.24        Install a specific version number";
            echo "    nvm use 0.10                Use the latest available 0.10.x release";
            echo "    nvm run 0.10.24 myApp.js    Run myApp.js using node v0.10.24";
            echo "    nvm alias default 0.10.24   Set default node version on a shell";
            echo;
            echo "Note:";
            echo "    to remove, delete or uninstall nvm - just remove ~/.nvm, ~/.npm and ~/.bower folders";
            echo
        ;;
        "install")
            local binavail;
            local t;
            local url;
            local sum;
            local tarball;
            local shasum='shasum';
            local nobinary;
            if ! has "curl"; then
                echo 'NVM Needs curl to proceed.' 1>&2;
            fi;
            if ! has "shasum"; then
                shasum='sha1sum';
            fi;
            if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
                nvm help;
                return;
            fi;
            shift;
            nobinary=0;
            if [ "$1" = "-s" ]; then
                nobinary=1;
                shift;
            fi;
            if [ "$os" = "freebsd" ]; then
                nobinary=1;
            fi;
            VERSION=`nvm_remote_version $1`;
            ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS='';
            shift;
            while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
                ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS="$ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS $1";
                shift;
            done;
            [ -d "$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" ] && echo "$VERSION is already installed." && return;
            if [ $nobinary -ne 1 ]; then
                if [ -n "$os" ]; then
                    binavail=;
                    case "$VERSION" in
                        v0.8.[012345])
                            binavail=0
                        ;;
                        v0.[1234567].*)
                            binavail=0
                        ;;
                        *)
                            binavail=1
                        ;;
                    esac;
                    if [ $binavail -eq 1 ]; then
                        t="$VERSION-$os-$arch";
                        url="http://nodejs.org/dist/$VERSION/node-${t}.tar.gz";
                        sum=`curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/$VERSION/SHASUMS.txt | \grep node-${t}.tar.gz | awk '{print $1}'`;
                        local tmpdir="$NVM_DIR/bin/node-${t}";
                        local tmptarball="$tmpdir/node-${t}.tar.gz";
                        if ( mkdir -p "$tmpdir" && curl -L -C - --progress-bar $url -o "$tmptarball" && nvm_checksum `${shasum} "$tmptarball" | awk '{print $1}'` $sum && tar -xzf "$tmptarball" -C "$tmpdir" --strip-components 1 && rm -f "$tmptarball" && mv "$tmpdir" "$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" ); then
                            nvm use $VERSION;
                            return;
                        else
                            echo "Binary download failed, trying source." 1>&2;
                            rm -rf "$tmptarball" "$tmpdir";
                        fi;
                    fi;
                fi;
            fi;
            echo "Additional options while compiling: $ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS";
            tarball='';
            sum='';
            make='make';
            if [ "$os" = "freebsd" ]; then
                make='gmake';
            fi;
            local tmpdir="$NVM_DIR/src";
            local tmptarball="$tmpdir/node-$VERSION.tar.gz";
            if [ "`curl -Is "http://nodejs.org/dist/$VERSION/node-$VERSION.tar.gz" | \grep '200 OK'`" != '' ]; then
                tarball="http://nodejs.org/dist/$VERSION/node-$VERSION.tar.gz";
                sum=`curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/$VERSION/SHASUMS.txt | \grep node-$VERSION.tar.gz | awk '{print $1}'`;
            else
                if [ "`curl -Is "http://nodejs.org/dist/node-$VERSION.tar.gz" | \grep '200 OK'`" != '' ]; then
                    tarball="http://nodejs.org/dist/node-$VERSION.tar.gz";
                fi;
            fi;
            if ( [ ! -z $tarball ] && mkdir -p "$tmpdir" && curl -L --progress-bar $tarball -o "$tmptarball" && if [ "$sum" = "" ]; then
                :;
            else
                nvm_checksum `${shasum} "$tmptarball" | awk '{print $1}'` $sum;
            fi && tar -xzf "$tmptarball" -C "$tmpdir" && cd "$tmpdir/node-$VERSION" && ./configure --prefix="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" $ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS && $make && rm -f "$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" 2> /dev/null && $make install ); then
                nvm use $VERSION;
                if ! has "npm"; then
                    echo "Installing npm...";
                    if [[ "`expr match $VERSION '\(^v0\.1\.\)'`" != '' ]]; then
                        echo "npm requires node v0.2.3 or higher";
                    else
                        if [[ "`expr match $VERSION '\(^v0\.2\.\)'`" != '' ]]; then
                            if [[ "`expr match $VERSION '\(^v0\.2\.[0-2]$\)'`" != '' ]]; then
                                echo "npm requires node v0.2.3 or higher";
                            else
                                curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | clean=yes npm_install=0.2.19 sh;
                            fi;
                        else
                            curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | clean=yes sh;
                        fi;
                    fi;
                fi;
            else
                echo "nvm: install $VERSION failed!";
                return 1;
            fi
        ;;
        "uninstall")
            [ $# -ne 2 ] && nvm help && return;
            if [[ $2 == `nvm_version` ]]; then
                echo "nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active node version, $2.";
                return 1;
            fi;
            VERSION=`nvm_version $2`;
            if [ ! -d $NVM_DIR/$VERSION ]; then
                echo "$VERSION version is not installed...";
                return;
            fi;
            t="$VERSION-$os-$arch";
            rm -rf "$NVM_DIR/src/node-$VERSION" "$NVM_DIR/src/node-$VERSION.tar.gz" "$NVM_DIR/bin/node-${t}" "$NVM_DIR/bin/node-${t}.tar.gz" "$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" 2> /dev/null;
            echo "Uninstalled node $VERSION";
            for A in `\grep -l $VERSION $NVM_DIR/alias/* 2>/dev/null`;
            do
                nvm unalias `basename $A`;
            done
        ;;
        "deactivate")
            if [[ $PATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/bin* ]]; then
                export PATH=${PATH%$NVM_DIR/*/bin*}${PATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/bin:};
                hash -r;
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/bin removed from \$PATH";
            else
                echo "Could not find $NVM_DIR/*/bin in \$PATH";
            fi;
            if [[ $MANPATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/share/man* ]]; then
                export MANPATH=${MANPATH%$NVM_DIR/*/share/man*}${MANPATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/share/man:};
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/share/man removed from \$MANPATH";
            else
                echo "Could not find $NVM_DIR/*/share/man in \$MANPATH";
            fi;
            if [[ $NODE_PATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules* ]]; then
                export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH%$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules*}${NODE_PATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules:};
                echo "$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules removed from \$NODE_PATH";
            else
                echo "Could not find $NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules in \$NODE_PATH";
            fi
        ;;
        "use")
            if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
                nvm help;
                return;
            fi;
            if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
                rc_nvm_version;
                if [ ! -z $RC_VERSION ]; then
                    VERSION=`nvm_version $RC_VERSION`;
                fi;
            else
                VERSION=`nvm_version $2`;
            fi;
            if [ -z $VERSION ]; then
                nvm help;
                return;
            fi;
            if [ -z $VERSION ]; then
                VERSION=`nvm_version $2`;
            fi;
            if [ ! -d "$NVM_DIR/$VERSION" ]; then
                echo "$VERSION version is not installed yet";
                return 1;
            fi;
            if [[ $PATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/bin* ]]; then
                PATH=${PATH%$NVM_DIR/*/bin*}$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/bin${PATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/bin};
            else
                PATH="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/bin:$PATH";
            fi;
            if [ -z "$MANPATH" ]; then
                MANPATH=$(manpath);
            fi;
            MANPATH=${MANPATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/man:};
            if [[ $MANPATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/share/man* ]]; then
                MANPATH=${MANPATH%$NVM_DIR/*/share/man*}$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/share/man${MANPATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/share/man};
            else
                MANPATH="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/share/man:$MANPATH";
            fi;
            if [[ $NODE_PATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules* ]]; then
                NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH%$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules*}$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/lib/node_modules${NODE_PATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules};
            else
                NODE_PATH="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH";
            fi;
            export PATH;
            hash -r;
            export MANPATH;
            export NODE_PATH;
            export NVM_PATH="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/lib/node";
            export NVM_BIN="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/bin";
            echo "Now using node $VERSION"
        ;;
        "run")
            if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
                nvm help;
                return;
            fi;
            VERSION=`nvm_version $2`;
            if [ ! -d $NVM_DIR/$VERSION ]; then
                echo "$VERSION version is not installed yet";
                return;
            fi;
            if [[ $NODE_PATH == *$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules* ]]; then
                RUN_NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH%$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules*}$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/lib/node_modules${NODE_PATH#*$NVM_DIR/*/lib/node_modules};
            else
                RUN_NODE_PATH="$NVM_DIR/$VERSION/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH";
            fi;
            echo "Running node $VERSION";
            NODE_PATH=$RUN_NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/$VERSION/bin/node "${@:3}"
        ;;
        "ls" | "list")
            print_versions "`nvm_ls $2`";
            if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
                echo -ne "current: \t";
                nvm_version current;
                nvm alias;
            fi;
            return
        ;;
        "ls-remote" | "list-remote")
            print_versions "`nvm_ls_remote $2`";
            return
        ;;
        "current")
            echo -ne "current: \t";
            nvm_version current
        ;;
        "alias")
            mkdir -p $NVM_DIR/alias;
            if [ $# -le 2 ]; then
                for ALIAS in $(nvm_set_nullglob; echo $NVM_DIR/alias/$2* );
                do
                    DEST=`cat $ALIAS`;
                    VERSION=`nvm_version $DEST`;
                    if [ "$DEST" = "$VERSION" ]; then
                        echo "$(basename $ALIAS) -> $DEST";
                    else
                        echo "$(basename $ALIAS) -> $DEST (-> $VERSION)";
                    fi;
                done;
                return;
            fi;
            if [ ! "$3" ]; then
                rm -f $NVM_DIR/alias/$2;
                echo "$2 -> *poof*";
                return;
            fi;
            mkdir -p $NVM_DIR/alias;
            VERSION=`nvm_version $3`;
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "! WARNING: Version '$3' does not exist." 1>&2;
            fi;
            echo $3 > "$NVM_DIR/alias/$2";
            if [ ! "$3" = "$VERSION" ]; then
                echo "$2 -> $3 (-> $VERSION)";
            else
                echo "$2 -> $3";
            fi
        ;;
        "unalias")
            mkdir -p $NVM_DIR/alias;
            [ $# -ne 2 ] && nvm help && return;
            [ ! -f $NVM_DIR/alias/$2 ] && echo "Alias $2 doesn't exist!" && return;
            rm -f $NVM_DIR/alias/$2;
            echo "Deleted alias $2"
        ;;
        "copy-packages")
            if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
                nvm help;
                return;
            fi;
            local VERSION=`nvm_version $2`;
            local ROOT=`(nvm use $VERSION && npm -g root) | tail -n1`;
            local ROOTDEPTH=$((`echo $ROOT | sed 's/[^\/]//g'|wc -m` -1));
            local INSTALLS;
            INSTALLS=(`nvm use $VERSION > /dev/null && npm -g -p ll | \grep "$ROOT\/[^/]\+$" | cut -d '/' -f $(($ROOTDEPTH + 2)) | cut -d ":" -f 2 | \grep -v npm | tr "\n" " "`);
            npm install -g ${INSTALLS[@]}
        ;;
        "clear-cache")
            rm -f $NVM_DIR/v* 2> /dev/null;
            echo "Cache cleared."
        ;;
        "version")
            print_versions "`nvm_version $2`"
        ;;
        *)
            nvm help
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Use `type` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212

Comment: @BroSlow it types source of `nvm`. I don't need it. I want to know where it is located

Comment: What? [tag:type] does pretty much the same thing [tag:which] does, except accesses more locations (aliases, functions, etc...), is faster, more portable, etc...

Comment: @BroSlow see update please

Comment: If the command is an alias then you can use 'type' <your command> to check alias.

Answer (score 7):

The `which` utility only searches your existing path for files, so if you cannot type "nvm" and have it run nvm, then which will not locate it.

On the other hand, `whereis` searches a hardcoded list of paths for the program, its manual page, and its source directory. It is possible that whereis will find something if nvm is not in your path, but if nvm is not in the hardcoded list of paths whereis searches, it will similarly be unsuccessful.

As you imply, `find` is a much more flexible utility for searching any path you desire for any type of file you can specify. If there is an nvm executable anywhere on your system, find can be used to hunt it down, regardless of it being in your system path.

A fourth option to look into would be the `locate` command, which uses an indexed database of files on your system to quickly find a file anywhere on your system, with a similarly simple invocation to which or whereis, e.g. `locate nvm`

Comment: `which` will correctly behave this way if you are using a C-shell variant, such as `csh` or `tcsh`.  It may work correctly in other shells as well.  However, in `bash` it does not work.  `bash` uses the `type` command instead.  It's perfectly possible for `which` to give you nothing in `bash` even when one *can* type `nvm` and have it work.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly related to the question, but sometimes `which` fails to find a file even though the file is on your path, and you can successfully execute the command in your shell. This can happen if you have used shell expansions on your path: your shell will use them but `which` may not.

For example, `which` will fail to find executables in in this directory (where ~ is expanded by your shell to your home directory):
`export PATH="$PATH:~/foo/bin"`

If you're using bash, you might as well get in the habit of using `type` instead of `which`, as it doesn't seem to have this problem. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212) for more alternatives.

Comment: This is important for anyone who comes from a `csh` or `tcsh` background.  I get bitten by this `bash` peculiarity almost every time I use `which`.

Answer (score 4):

If you've used curl to install nvm (and possibly other methods), it will install itself as a set of shell functions in your home directory, in a hidden folder called `.nvm/nvm.sh`. As it is not a command (explained in the other answers) this is why `whereis` and `which` fail to find it. Note that the same directory has a Readme.markdown which contains quite a bit of detailed information about nvm.

This is the script you can curl to install nvm:
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.17.3/install.sh

I had the same problem and poking through that revealed where it was installing itself, so that might be a useful method for finding out where other commands live when they are not actually commands.

This is great explanation by the author of nvm about how nvm.sh works:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/521

In short, nvm is a collection of shell functions, and even though it has the .sh extension, is not actually a shell script. This is why it does not have executable permissions (and should not be changed). To run it, it instead must be 'sourced':

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

The dot is a synonym for the 'source' command. Sourcing it makes the functions within the file available to the current shell. If for instance you need to run nvm from a shell script, which opens a new shell for the duration of the script, you will need to source nvm in the file because it won't be available otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If your `nvm` command is actually an alias or a shell function, `which` will identify it only if you use an appropriate option (e.g., `--read-alias` or `--read-functions`; see `which(1)`), and `whereis` will be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

`whereis` and `which` only search specific locations.

`man whereis`:

> The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.

`man which`:

> The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run had these commands actually been invoked.

*Path* refers to the `PATH` environment variable. ([Read more about it](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them))

So these utilities will only find programs that are in one of the default locations (e.g. `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` etc.) and could be launched by just typing the command name.

If you installed `npm` somewhere else, e.g. `/home/username/bin/npm`, and that directory is not in your `PATH`, it won't be found this way. You'll need to use e.g. `find`.

Comment: I believe that `nvm` in the PATH since I can access this command from any directory

Comment: `which` can fail to find things in the path in some cases when using `bash`.  See @Pathogen's answer above.